# NICE RPA 4.6 Button not triggered in the automation process of websites

Tags: rpa

I am new to nice RPA real time designer tool.  In the physical objects layer i have captured all the fields correctly and it is working fine.  And in the business entities layer i have created types and instances for all the entities.  The problem i have is that in the work flow layer.  My RPA automatically launches internet explorer and opens flipkart.com and in the search box automatically types iphone and needs to click on the search icon.  Everything works but except the search button.  Button is not triggered automatically as mentioned in the work flow.  Not only this search button, none of the buttons are not triggered automatically as mentioned in the work flow. None of the buttons are triggered while automating the process in websites.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any errors during execution? Did you add a wait stage after launch?

Answer (score 0):

My experience with developing NICE Real-Time Designer is basically developing hacks and workarounds all the time. We had cases like this where the framework was basically ignoring commands, tackling them was mostly done by:

1. Insert a small-duration wait command right before the line which is not executed, this sometimes helps.
2. See if you can circumvent the button somehow, i.e. by not clicking on it, but rather using keyboard commands to shift the focus from the search field to the butting and then sending a keyboard ENTER command
3. If the site you're automating is not an SPA, probably you can access the results page directly by fabricating the necessary link in code and then going directly there.

Whatever you do, just keep in mind that RTD actually does not care about the success of operations once they're executed: If you have to make sure that some field is filled in or some button is clicked, loop the state in the workflow until it is.